# SQL Alternative

Tags: sql, case

Is there a better way to approach this SQL

Sometimes I have income = 0 in certain cases, I need the monthly income divided by the non zero Income in a particular month

```
SELECT   "CLASS",
         "SCHOOL",
         "Year",
         "MONTH",
         Sum("JanIncome")/Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN "JanIncome">0 THEN 1
                  ELSE NULL
         END) AS "JanAvg"
         Sum("FebIncome")/Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN "FebIncome">0 THEN 1
                  ELSE NULL
         END) AS "FebAvg"
FROM     (
                SELECT *
                FROM   school )
GROUP BY "CLASS",
         "SCHOOL",
         "Year",
         "MONTH";
```

Comment: `from ( Select * from School)` can be just `from School`

Comment: Do you want to use all the days in the month, ex. January 31 or just the average of non-zero values?

Comment: Just the Avg of non zero values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just nulling out the `0`s and using the built in `AVG`:

```
SELECT "CLASS","SCHOOL","Year","MONTH",
  AVG(NULLIF("JanIncome",0)) AS "JanAvg",
  AVG(NULLIF("FebIncome",0)) as "FebAvg"
```

[`AVG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177677.aspx) ignores nulls.

Comment: Damien, Just have a follow up question Say i have 3 records with values 7, 0, 2 --- in this case AVG(NULLIF("JanIncome",0)) AS "JanAvg",  would result 9/2 = 4.5 or 9/3 = 3 ..

Comment: @Ram - 4.5. If you're not experienced with this sort of thing, it's worth setting up a database server on your machine and getting familiar with temp tables or table variables (or using [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)) - in the time it takes to get answers to these types of questions, you could try things out for yourself and see how it works.